# How to insert an algorithm inline with an item in itemize/enumerate

Tags: formatting, itemize, algorithms, algorithmic

I am using an itemize to list several algorithms, and I want to use the algorithm package to display the algorithm.

However, when I use the \begin{algorithm} within one of the items, the algorithm stretches across the entire width of the page, whereas I want it to be in line with the start of the item.

How do I do this?

For reference, this is what my incorrect latex looks like:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item this algorithm .....
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm 1}\label{alg:cap}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \state{algorithm step}
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \item ...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe nest  it in a minipage of width `\linewidth` (which is different from `\textwidth` in a standard list environment).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a floating environment although you want the algorithm to be fixed in a list. You can therefore omit the algorithm environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocodex}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item this algorithm .....
    \item Algorithm 1:\label{alg:cap}
          \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $i \gets 10$
            \If{$i\geq 5$} 
              \State $i \gets i-1$
            \Else
              \If{$i\leq 3$}
                \State $i \gets i+2$
              \EndIf
            \EndIf 
          \end{algorithmic}
    \item ...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** Some lines above and below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocodex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item this algorithm .....
    \item Algorithm 1:\label{alg:cap}
          \item[] elegant line above
          \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $i \gets 10$
            \If{$i\geq 5$} 
              \State $i \gets i-1$
            \Else
              \If{$i\leq 3$}
                \State $i \gets i+2$
              \EndIf
            \EndIf 
          \end{algorithmic}
          \item[] elegant line below
    \item ...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to tweak linespacing etc. see the documentation of [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)

Comment: Is there an elegant way to add the lines above and below the algorithm?

Comment: I added some lines above and below, maybe they are elegant